# What's the difference between ZFC+Grothendieck, ZFC+inaccessible cardinals and Tarski-Grothendieck set theory?

Tags: lo.logic, formal-languages, large-cardinals, set-theory, axioms

Say that "U" is the axiom that "For each set x, there exists a Grothendieck universe U such that x $\in$ U", where Grothendieck universes are defined in the usual way (or, if that's unclear, in [this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe)). Also, say that "Ca" is the axiom that "For each cardinal κ, there is a strongly inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ which is strictly larger than κ."

It's known that ZFC+U and ZFC+Ca are completely equivalent and prove the same sentences. A sentence is a theorem of ZFC+U iff it's a theorem of ZFC+Ca.

In addition to the above, there's also Tarski-Grothendieck set theory, which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory). The axioms of TG are

1. The axiom stating everything is a set
2. The axiom of extensionality from ZFC
3. The axiom of regularity from ZFC
4. The axiom of pairing from ZFC
5. The axiom of union from ZFC
6. The axiom schema of replacement from ZFC
7. Tarski's axiom A

Tarski's axiom A states that for any set $x$, there exists a set $y$ containing, $x$ itself, every subset of every member of $y$, the power set of every member of $y$, and every subset of $y$ of cardinality less than $y$.

These three axioms from ZFC are then implied as theorems of TG:

1. The axiom of infinity
2. The axiom of power set
3. The axiom schema of specification
4. The axiom of choice

My question is as follows: is TG also completely equivalent to ZFC+U and ZFC+Ca, equivalent in the same sense that something is a theorem of TG iff it's a theorem of the other two? Is TG just an axiomatization of ZFC+U/ZFC+Ca which removes redundant axioms and allows them to just be theorems? Or is there some subtle difference between TG and ZFC+U/ZFC+Ca, in that there's some sentence which TG proves that's undecidable in ZFC+U/ZFC+Ca or vice versa?

In other words, instead of typing ZFC+Grothendieck, can I just type TG and be referencing a different axiomatization of the exact same thing?

Comment: "C" already denotes the axiom of choice, so it's not the best abbreviation for another axiom.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll change it to "Ca".

Comment: This is not an answer, but a repetition of my linked questions already stated in <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28389>.
1/ Is it possible to dispense with axiom 4 (the axiom of pairing from ZF(C)) to develop the Tarski-Grothendieck (TG) set theory?
2/ Does anybody know how to prove the 16 equivalences between conditions of axioms A and A' of Tarski ?
Gérard Lang

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.  Assume ZFC.  If there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals, then Tarski's Axiom A holds because whenever $\kappa$ is inaccessible, the rank initial segment $V_\kappa$ of $V$ is a Tarski set.  Conversely, if Tarski's Axiom A holds then for every set $x$ there is a Tarski set $y$ with $x \in y$.  We will show that $|y|$ is an inaccessible cardinal greater than $|x|$, proving the existence of a proper class of inaccessible cardinals.

To show that the cardinality $\kappa$ of $y$ is a strong limit cardinal, given $\zeta < \kappa$ we take a subset $z$ of $y$ of size $\zeta$.  We have $z \in y$ because $y$ contains its small subsets.  Then we have $\mathcal{P}(z) \in y$ because $y$ is closed under the power set operation.  Finally $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(z)) \subset y$ because $y$ contains all subsets of its elements.  This shows that $2^{2^{\zeta}} \le \kappa$ and therefore that $2^{\zeta} < \kappa$.

To show that the cardinality $\kappa$ of $y$ is regular, notice that if $\kappa$ is singular then by the closure of $y$ under small subsets we can get a family of $\kappa^{cof(\kappa)}$ many distinct sets in $y$, contradicting the fact that $\kappa^{cof( \kappa)} > \kappa$ (which is an instance of Koenig's Theorem.)

Comment: I always thought that it was $2$-inaccessible (which is slightly stronger than a proper class of inaccessibles) that was equivalent to the TG axioms. 

Comment: Is a 2-inaccessible an inaccessible limit of inaccessibles?  In this case, if $\kappa$ is 2-inaccessible, then $V_\kappa$ is a model of TG.

Comment: Stefan, yes. Indeed if $\kappa$ is $2$-inaccessible then $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC+proper class of inaccessible. I suppose that I get the minor difference.

Comment: OK Trevor, that makes sense. One lingering question I have, though, is - within the context of ZFC, do the existence of Tarski sets imply the existence of Grothendieck universes and vice versa? The former don't have to be transitive, but the latter do. Is the idea that they're equivalent in ZFC but not in ZF or something? I've seen some reference to the idea that ZF+Tarski's implies AC but that ZF+U doesn't, and that implying AC from the getgo causes the additional assertion of the existence of either Tarski and Grothendieck universes to imply one another.

Comment: Also, I'm slightly confused - I got a note in my MathOverflow email update for this question (from you?) telling me to look at the accepted answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28389/about-grothendieck-universe-and-tarskis-a-and-a-axioms

It looks like ZFC+Ca is equivalent to ZFC+Tarski, but ZFC+"There is a proper class of Tarski sets" doesn't imply ZFC+Ca, because Tarski sets aren't transitive and hence ZFC+"there is exactly one inaccessible cardinal" would also be a model of ZFC+"There is a proper class of Tarski sets." And that seems consistent with what you wrote.

Comment: @Mike: I'll respond to your second comment first, regarding my other attempt at answering this question, which I deleted quickly but it looks like you were still notified of.  If there is a single inaccessible cardinal then for every $x$ there is a Tarski set $y$ with $\lbrace x \rbrace \in y$, and this implies that there is a proper class of Tarski sets, but it does not imply Tarski's axiom that for every $x$ there is a Tarski set $y$ with $x \in y$.

Comment: @Mike: regarding your first comment, modulo ZFC all three axioms are equivalent by what I wrote combined with what you wrote (that ZFC+U and ZFC+Ca are equivalent.)  It does seem to be known that Tarski's Axiom A is not equivalent to the other two under ZF for the reason you said.

Comment: Great. Much thanks for the clear explanation. I guess I can abbreviate "ZFC+Grothendieck universes exist" to "TG" from now on.