# Tarski-Grothendieck set theory, the axiom of pairing and the axiom of specification

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

I am building upon MO question 102846 concerning the Tarski-Grothendieck set theory (TG).
I have two questions;
1/ I think that it is possible that the axiom of pairing (axiom 4 of the TG theory presented in question 102846) could be deleted. So, my question is: Is axiom 4 independant of the others axioms of the TG set theory ?
2/ In the considered question, it is asserted that the axiom of specification is a consequence of Tarski"s axiom A. My question is: what are the others axioms needed to have this result and could I have a proof ?
Gérard Lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume all the axioms of TG except for pairing.  We will show that pairing and specification (a.k.a. separation) both follow, with the caveat in the following paragraph.

We will also assume that the empty set exists.  This does not seem to follow from the TG axioms as defined in the linked question [What's the difference between ZFC+Grothendieck, ZFC+inaccessible cardinals and Tarski-Grothendieck set theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102846/) or on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski-Grothendieck_set_theory, which do not seem to imply either "there is a set" or "if there is a set then there is an empty set."   The natural way to proceed seems to be to postulate the existence of the empty set.

(1) For pairing, suppose we are given sets $x$ and $y$ and we want to form the pair $\lbrace x,y \rbrace$. Let $A$ be a Tarski set containing $x$.  Then $A$ also contains some element other than $x$ (this can be seen by considering separately the two cases $x = \emptyset$ and $x \ne \emptyset$.)  Define a class function $F$ with domain $A$ by
\begin{equation}
F(z) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $z = x$}\newline
y &\text{if $z \in A$ and $z \ne x$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The range of $F$ is $\lbrace x,y \rbrace$, which is a set by replacement.

(2) For specification, let $A$ be a set and $\varphi$ be a formula.  We want to show that the class $B = \lbrace x \in A : \varphi(x)\rbrace$ is a set.  If $B$ is empty then we are done because the empty set exists.  So we may assume that there is $x_0 \in A$ such that $\varphi(x_0)$ holds.  Then $B$ is the range of the class function
$F$ with domain $A$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x \in A$ and $\varphi(x)$}\newline
x_0 &\text{if $x \in A$ and $\neg \varphi(x)$},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
so it is a set by replacement.

Comment: Dear Trevor,
I have the following question with your proof (1). It seems that you need the pairing concept o build the function concept. So, if you are using a function to prove the pairing axiom, how to be sure that we are not having a vicious circle ?
Gérard Lang 

Comment: Dear Gérard, that is a good question.  I'm using the term "class function" to refer to the defining formula of F together with parameters in the definition ($x$ and $y$.)  So it's not *a priori* an object in the domain of discourse, it's just shorthand for a syntactical notion.  This may be an abuse of notation but it's common in set theory.  To translate what I wrote into a formal proof, one uses the instance of the replacement schema corresponding to the formula that defines F as a binary relation. 

Comment: I should add that it's important that we consider $F$ as a binary relation, not as a unary relation on ordered pairs, or else your objection would apply. In the (ostensible) absence of the pairing axiom the difference becomes rather confusing and one has to look at the formal statement of the replacement axiom schema to understand what is going on.

Comment: E.g., for (1) we are using the instance of the replacement axiom schema corresponding to the formula $\varphi$ with parameters $x$, $y$, and $A$ given by $\varphi(z,t) \iff z = t = x \text{ or } (z \in A \text{ and } z \ne x \text{ and } t = y)$.

Comment: Dear Trevor, thank you for your precisions. here are some comments.
A/Concerning my question 2, your proof is the classical derivation of the separation schema from the replacement schema.I was hoping, in the context of the assertion of question Mo 10284O that the axiom of specification/separation is a consequence of axiom A of Tarski, to have a proof of the separation axiom from axiom A without replacement.  More precisely, I was hoping to have a derivation of the schema of separation from the TG  set theory minus Replacement.
B/Concerning question 1, I fear I am not completely convinced.

Comment: Regarding your question 2, I think it is very unlikely that in any reasonable fragment of set theory one can prove either separation or replacement without alreadly assuming something like separation or replacement---they are very different from all the other axioms.  I see no indication in the linked question that such a proof is possible from TG minus replacement, and in particular I don't see how Tarski's axiom A could help.

Comment: Regarding question 1, maybe the thing that I called "$F$" is confusing, so let's forget about it.  The formula $\varphi$ in my comment above has the property that for any $z \in A$ there is exactly one $t$ such that $\varphi(z,t)$ holds.  Therefore the replacement axiom corresponding to $\varphi$ says something, namely that there is a set $p$ such that for every $t$ we have $t \in p$ if and only if $\varphi(z,t)$ holds for some $z \in A$.  This set $p$ satisfies the definition of $\lbrace x, y\rbrace$.

Comment: By the way, when I say that I don't think Tarski's axiom A implies separation, I should clarify that axiom A gives the existence of sets that contain all their small subsets *that are already known to exist as sets*.  Axiom A does not by itself give sets that contain all their small definable subclasses.

Comment: 1/I agree with you that it seems unlikely that TG minus replacement could prove separation. This is why I asked my second question, based on the assertion contained in MO 102846 that axiom A had "specification" as a consequence. I was aware of proofs for the three others assertions that axiom A proves power set, infinity and choice (see the METAMATH site by Norman Megill for example); so i hoped something interesting could come !
2/ My question 1 is based on my hope that the pairing  axiom could be deleted from the TG axioms. In fact, the problem is to express the fourth condition of axiom A. 

Comment: (1) MO 102846 just said specification was a consequence of TG, not that specification comes from Axiom A in the same way that, say, the power set axiom does.  Indeed, the proof of specification in my answer does not use Axiom A, and I don't see any proof of specification that *does* use Axiom A in any meaningful way.  (2) It's true that the meaning of the condition 4 in the definition of a Tarski set---"y contains every subset of y of cardinality less than that of y"---is ambiguous without pairing, but the proof of pairing in my answer only used conditions 1-3 so I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: Dear Trevor, let me thank you for this interesting exchange about the TG set theory. I still have some doubts about the full formal correctness of your derivation of the axiom of pairing from TG minus pairing, but I will credit you for your answer. Bien cordialement.GL

Comment: Dear Gérard, thanks for accepting my answer.  I agree that the absence of pairing does make it tricky to write and interpret informal proofs.  Probably at this point you could write a formal proof of (1) if you are so inclined.